# PHPのJSON_PRETTY_PRINTについて

Tags: php

お世話になります。
PHPで

```
echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

のようにすると、インデントで整形された形でJSONを出力することができます。
それで、この際のインデント文字をタブ文字に変更したいのですが、何か方法はありますでしょうか。
何か良い方法をご存知でしたら、教えていただけると幸いです。

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[本家SOに似たような質問](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29837570/)がありました。
こちらは空白4つを2つにしたいということでしたが、
タブ文字に置換するのも対して変わりません。

```
$data = ['some' => 'data'];
$json = preg_replace_callback ('/^ +/m', function ($m) {
  return str_repeat ("¥t", strlen ($m[0]) / 4);//空白数(4つ)で割った数分タブ文字を返却
}, json_encode ($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

`JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`自体には整形文字の指定は無かったと思います。

Comment: すみません、本家のほうは見ていませんでした。ありがとうございました。解決しました。